# Can't link\import proto files from different folders

Tags: c#, visual-studio, grpc

I have 2 proto files somewhere outside the project.

**common\v1\timestamp_offset.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "google/protobuf/duration.proto";

package common.v1;

message TimestampOffset
{
    google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 1;
    google.protobuf.Duration offset = 2;
}
```

**booking\v1\booking.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "common/v1/timestamp_offset.proto";

package booking.v1;

message Booking{
    int32 id = 1;
    int32 carrier_id = 2;
    int32 customer_id = 3;
    string booking_type = 4;
    string travel_type = 5;
    common.v1.TimestampOffset time = 6;
}
```

I need to link files into project for using them.
With such options it doesn't work. I get *Import "common/v1/timestamp_offset.proto" was not found or had errors.*

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="..\Protos\booking\v1\booking.proto" Link="booking\v1\booking.proto"/>
  <Protobuf Include="..\Protos\common\v1\timestamp_offset.proto" Link="common\v1\timestamp_offset.proto"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

I found. All will be fine if I move both files inside project.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="booking\v1\booking.proto"/>
  <Protobuf Include="common\v1\timestamp_offset.proto"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Hi Nodon, what your question?

Comment: @AndyK I have got answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to `Include` etc, the `<Protobuf>` element allows you to specify a `ProtoRoot="something"` attribute, which is used to specify the root when resolving imports etc; this is *probably* the bit you're missing. This is documented [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/HEAD/src/csharp/BUILD-INTEGRATION.md#that_s-good-so-far_but-i-do-not-want-the-and-directories-in-my-tree)